# "#NAME?" error in excel when calling dll C++ function

Tags: c++, excel, vba, dll

I want to run C++ functions in Excel, but I keep getting the "#NAME?" error when I try to call them.
I am using Visual Studio 2015 and Excel 2016.

.cpp file (temp.cpp):

```
_declspec(dllexport) double _stdcall square(double x)
{
    return x*x;
}
```

Declaration in Excel VBA:

```
Declare Function square _
Lib "c:\users\rune\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\temp\Debug\temp.dll" Alias "?square@@YGNN@Z" (ByVal x As Double) As Double
```

Here is what I did:

In Visual Studio, at “File\New\Project\Win32 Console Application,” I selected “DLL” under “Application type” and “Empty project” under “Additional options” (I unchecked “Security Development Lifecycle [SDL] checks”).
I Changed the Calling Convention to “__stdcall (/Gz)” at “Project\Properties\Configuration Properties\C/C++\Advanced.”
Then I compiled the project.

In Excel, I added a new module with the declaration and tried the following formula in a cell:

```
=square(10)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Put the call in a public VBA function in a module, call the VBA function from the worksheet

Comment: I tried the code `Range("d7").Value = square(10)` in VBA and that does work. Thanks much. But why does it not work in an Excel cell? The tutorial I followed did it exactly that way.

Comment: AFAIK you need to wrap api calls in VBA

Comment: Well, it is from VBA i plan to access the code ultimately anyway, so that is no obstacle at all. Thanks much.